# How to spatially join OSM point to road data?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, fields-attributes, attribute-joins

Using QGIS 2.16.1 , using shape layers, with the same CRS, I am having two  line and a point layer.  The point layer was added by the plugin : locate points along lines" The third layer is the downloaded layer "roads" (shape-OSM) from geofabrik. I want to add the streetnames from the roads layer to the points layer. The points are on te line.....  If possible without extra steps like buffers..

[image]

[image]

Which spatial join should I use? And, do I use intersect/touches/crosses etc?

Comment: Off the top of my head 'Join by location' should do the job

Answer (score 1):

What you want is transferring attributes from one geometry to another depending on how they relate so the tool to use is "Join attributes by location".

You want to transfer them if they touch in any way so just use "intersects".

As there is zero chance that your points actually lie on the infinitely thin vector lines, you should adjust the "precision" value. What kind of value makes sense depends on your data and coordinate reference system. An alternative would be buffering the points, joining the attributes to the buffers, then join them back to the points on "within".

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for answering!  I couldn't find the "join by location"in QGIS 2.16.1 After deleting the other QGIS versions I could. But it didn't do the job for me really.

So, I chose another way: in stead of buffering the points, I buffered the network, so that the points are within it! Then I used the "spatial join" plugin. This works great for me!